# Add values in ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have an array which will be listed in html with `*ngFor`, this array will have some values i need to calculate the the value listed in html, i should not use .ts file, And i need the total value to be displayed in another row

```
<ion-grid>
     <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dailyDays"> 
          <ion-col>{{item.price}}</ion-col>
     </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<ion-row> total should be here  </ion-row>


    dailyDays = [];
this.dailyDays.push({   day: element,
                        month: this.currentDate.getMonth(),
                        year: this.currentDate.getFullYear(),
                        price: data.price,
                        brand: data.selectedBrand,
                        howManyDay: data.selectedDay,
                        check: "true",
                        quantity: data.selectedQuantity
                });
```

this price will get varied on page load, so i should use only .html file to get total price value

```
 final(){
            console.log("this will have an array of objects", this.dailyDays);
            var array = this.dailyDays;
            var total= 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var element = array[i];
                console.log(element.price);
                // how to add each price and get a total 
                total += element.price;
                console.log(total);
            }

        }
```

The problem i get is

[[image: The problem is i need a single] value as total[1]]

Comment: You said, it needs to be displayed on page load right, it means you can put your code in .ts file. because on page load component will load and on component load, you can either write your code in constructor or ngOnInit Hook.

Comment: ok that total should come at end of a function because the displayed value is the final value @WasifKhan

Comment: what do you mean by _this price will get varied on page load_? is that because of the interaction of the user, or because of an asyc method?

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan kindly show us your component code where you are getting dailyDays.

Comment: please elaborate it with some example , what array you have and what is your desire output

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan how are you loading array, using async. call to server?

Comment: no server call only accessing local storage to store and retrieve data

Comment: If you generate the HTML from data, then just calculate the price from the data and bind to the result in HTML to get it displayed. Reading values from HTML that is generated by Angular is in most cases just the worst way to do it.

Comment: check update @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: What's the problem with `// how to add each price and get a total`?. Just `total += element.propertyWithPrice;`

Comment: @Yokesh Varadhan just use a for loop below your push code to get total price.

Comment: You also need to assign the result to a property outside the method (directly on the components class) in order to be able to bind to it in the template.

Comment: Seems like the price is a string and not a number. Try with `total += parseFloat(element.price);`

Comment: it worked thank you all

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you please add an answer with the working code and accept it so we can close the issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under several discussion and confusion i got an answer, since making calculation in .html is a worst approach i worked with .ts file

```
final(){
        console.log("this will have an array of objects", this.dailyDays);
        var array = this.dailyDays;

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var element = array[i];
            console.log(element.price);
            // how to add each price and get a total 
            this.total += parseFloat(element.price);

        }

        console.log(this.total);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply Use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sumBy%22Lodash%22). and it shuld be like this :

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dailyDays"> 
      <ion-col>{{item.price}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<ion-row>{{_.sumBy(dailiDays, 'price')}}</ion-row>
```